# Datepicker in silverstripe

Tags: jquery-ui-datepicker, silverstripe

```
class Article extends Page { // Model
static $db = array(
   'Date' => 'Date',
   'Author'=>'Text'
);
 private static $has_one = array(

);
function getCMSFields() {
   $fields = parent::getCMSFields();

 $fields->addFieldToTab('Root.Content.Main', $date = new DateField('Date'),'Content');
 DateField::create('MyDate')->setConfig('showcalendar', true);
  $fields->addFieldToTab('Root.Content.Main', new TextField('Author'), 'Content');
          return $fields;
   }    
}
```

The above code should show datepicker but it is not showing.. 
Plz help me with this..

Comment: sorry the question is not post properly..Hope ual understand.

Comment: As previously suggested to you, go through the [Silverstripe tutorials](http://doc.silverstripe.org/framework/en/tutorials) to get a basic understanding of how to work with Silverstripe. If you were to go through and follow [Tutorial 2](http://doc.silverstripe.org/framework/en/tutorials/2-extending-a-basic-site#adding-date-and-author-fields) you would see it shows you exactly how to add the Datepicker: http://doc.silverstripe.org/framework/en/tutorials/2-extending-a-basic-site#adding-date-and-author-fields

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
$fields->addFieldToTab('Root.Content.Main', DateField::create('MyDate')->setConfig('showcalendar', true),'Content');
```

DateField::create() is a Factory Method for DateField, so it will return a DateField object.

Comment: `$dateField = new DateField('Date', 'Blog Date');
  $dateField->setConfig('showcalendar', true);
  $fields->addFieldToTab('Root.Main', $dateField, "Content");`